# Powershell check types of int and double

Tags: powershell, integer, double

I need the user to fill in an integer, but with the code shown beneath, also doubles are allowed. How can I change it to allow only integers?

```
do{

    $opgegevenGetal = read-host "Enter an integer"

    if(![bool]($opgegevenGetal -as [int])){
        write-host "Only integers please"
    }

}

until ([bool]($opgegevenGetal -as [int]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
do{
    $opgegevenGetal = read-host "Enter an integer"
    $a = ""
    if(  ![int32]::TryParse( $opgegevenGetal , [ref]$a ))
      {
        write-host "Only integers please"
      }
  } until ($a -gt 0)
```

Codes for accept `0` as input:

```
do{
    $opgegevenGetal = read-host "Enter an integer"
    $a = ""
    if(  ![int32]::TryParse( $opgegevenGetal , [ref]$a ))
      {
        write-host "Only integers please"
      }
  } until ($a -gt 0 -or $opgegevenGetal -eq '0')
```

or:

```
do{
    $opgegevenGetal = read-host "Enter an integer"
    $a = ""
    $b = [int32]::TryParse( $opgegevenGetal , [ref]$a )
    if(  !$b)
      {
        write-host "Only integers please"
      }
  } until ($b)
```

Comment: @Tomzie Just a precisation: if user input `0` (because the untill test ) the loop doesn't exit. If is a problem I'll post an easy way to solve it.

Comment: A little more compact version: `$value = 0; $read = Read-Host 'Enter an integer'; while( ![int]::TryParse( $read, [ref]$value ) ) { $read = Read-Host 'Only integers please' }`

Answer (score 6):

A little more compact version of [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701172/2495):

```
$value = 0
$read = Read-Host 'Enter an integer'
while( ![int]::TryParse( $read, [ref]$value ) ) {
  $read = Read-Host 'Only integers please'
}
```